# How to convert SOLR query to Solarj Query

Tags: solr, solrj

When on the Solr admin screen, we can see the queries being
[image of query generated on Solr Admin search page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ6M1.png)

`{!term f=email}xyz@mail.dice.com`

What is the significance of `{!term f=xxx}` here? Where can I get details about this syntax? And how can I translate this to a query using SolrJ api calls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [syntax is called local params](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_7/local-parameters-in-queries.html) - it changes the behavior of the query to use a different query parser or do something special (like tagging it with an internal tag to reference it in another part of the query).

In your case it [invokes the `term` query parser](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_7/other-parsers.html#term-query-parser).

> TermQParser extends the QParserPlugin by creating a single term query from the input value equivalent to readableToIndexed(). This is useful for generating filter queries from the external human readable terms returned by the faceting or terms components. The only parameter is f, for the field.

If I remember correctly (and from a short bit of searching) you should be able to give it directly to `setQuery`:

```
.setQuery("{!term f=email}xyz@mail.dice.com");
```